# Legal of nested radicals

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

$\sqrt{20+ \sqrt{96}+\sqrt{12}} = \sqrt9 + \sqrt6 + \sqrt3 - \sqrt2$.
Hi, What legal in math cause this statement?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Are you asking why / whether the two expressions are equal?

Comment: Yes, I want to find why these expressions are equal

Comment: A solution for this is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511485/denesting-sqrt20-sqrt96-sqrt12-into-four-possible-radicals), as this is closed now.

Answer (score 3):

Use the equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{\alpha}+\sqrt{\beta}=\sqrt{\alpha+\beta+2\sqrt{\alpha\beta}} \\
\sqrt{\alpha}-\sqrt{\beta}=\sqrt{\alpha+\beta-2\sqrt{\alpha\beta} }
\end{eqnarray*}
In your case ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2} & =&\sqrt{15+6\sqrt{6}}+\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}} \\
& =&\sqrt{20+4 \sqrt{6}+2 \sqrt{(15+6\sqrt{6})(5-2\sqrt{6})}} \\
& =& \sqrt{20+\sqrt{96}+\sqrt{12}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: If I want to get from the left expression to the right expression, what to do?

Comment: You could run the whole argument backwards ... but I guess you want a general method for decomposing nested radicals into a sum of "singleton" radicals ?

Comment: Yes, I want a general method